# Redirect indvidual portfolio pages to main portfolio index page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, portfolio

I have a number of individual portfolio pages, such as the screenshot, so:

- http://imjustcreative.com/portfolio/adxprs
- http://imjustcreative.com/portfolio/asterisk

I need all of these to redirect to the main Portfolio index page:

- http://imjustcreative.com/portfolio/

I also have a domain pointer from :

- http://imjustcreative.co.uk/

to

- http://imjustcreative.com

(the .com is my main domain as set-up in Google), but would need instances of the .co.uk/portfolio/adxprs etc to work the same as the .com

Hope that makes sense,

Thank you for your help,
Graham
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try RedirectMatch

```
RedirectMatch ^/portfolio/(adxprs|asterisk)/?$ http://imjustcreative.com/portfolio/
```

This will redirect

```
 ^/portfolio/(adxprs|asterisk)/?$
 <= /portfolio/adxprsORasterist/optional slash
```

to

```
=> http://imjustcreative.com/portfolio/
```